# ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I use iSQLPlus to create table and when i reference multiple foreign keys, they give me error `ORA-02270`:

```
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

Here is my code:

```
create table People
(name varchar(50),
ssn varchar(50) not null,
G# varchar(50),
primary key (ssn),
unique(ssn, G#))

create table Professor
(
name varchar(50),
ssn varchar(50) not null,
G# varchar(50),
teach_record varchar(50),
primary key (ssn),
unique (ssn, G#),
foreign key (name, ssn, G#) references People(name, ssn, G#) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

It says error on the line before the ")" in professor script, which references People(name, ssn, G#)
I couldnt figure what the problem is.

Comment: You need a primary key on People(name, ssn, G#) in order to create a foreign key on it.

Comment: Florin is right; but why are you duplicating the `name` and `G#` columns in the `professor` table in the first place? Since `ssn` is a primary key in the `people` table, and therefor unique, you can just join the table together to get those values. Otherwise, if say the person's name changed (through marriage or whatever) then you'd have to manage updating the value in both tables simultaneous, which would also mean updating a primary key - something that is not usually desirable.

Comment: This is a ISA relationship. I want to say the prof table inherit attributes from People.

Comment: To create a FK, the parent key may have a UNIQUE constraint, non necessarily a PK constraint.

Comment: 'Inherits' in the object sense, or the relational sense? An FK on `people(ssn)` still says that a professor is a person, and would 'inherit' the name etc. from the related `people` record. You are not really saying that `professor` is a subtype - you can't insert a record *only* in professor, if that's what you mean. I may very well not be understanding what you mean, or what you want *8-)

Comment: Oh no, I understand what you mean. I mean in relational sense, not object. Cavasilva's answer is perfect. All i need to do is make the other attribute unique for People.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table People
(name varchar(50),
ssn varchar(50) not null,
G# varchar(50),
primary key (ssn),
unique(name, ssn, G#))

create table Professor
(
name varchar(50),
ssn varchar(50) not null,
G# varchar(50),
teach_record varchar(50),
primary key (ssn),
unique (ssn, G#),
foreign key (name, ssn, G#) references People(name, ssn, G#) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```